# Ubuntu Oneiric Install Fails

Tags: rosinstall, ubuntu-oneiric, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I follow the directions for installing I am given this in response:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-electric-desktop-full : Depends: ros-electric-vision-opencv (= 1.6.7-s1320939105~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-pipeline (= 1.6.3-s1320939324~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: ros-electric-image-transport-plugins (= 1.4.2-s1320939218~oneiric) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas on what the problem is?

I'm on a fresh install of 11.10 i386 Ubuntu. I've tried with a different mirror with the same results

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11972/ubuntu-oneiric-install-fails/) by [sb-rosq](https://answers.ros.org/users/1398/sb-rosq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-11-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sb-rosq](https://answers.ros.org/users/1398/sb-rosq/) on 2011-11-16**:
I'm on a fresh install of 11.10 i386 Ubuntu. I've tried with a different mirror with the same results.

**Comment by [mobadr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1168/mobadr/) on 2011-11-16**:
I got this error as well after recently reinstalling ubuntu, it was working just fine when I installed it about a month ago but I've removed ubuntu to try openSuse and fedora and when I reinstalled ubuntu again I got this error, have there been any updates in the ROS repositories or packages?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-16**:
What is your system setup?  Distro arch etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Oneiric i386 was not updated until this afternoon for the new release of opencv.  It should be synced now.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sb-rosq](https://answers.ros.org/users/1398/sb-rosq/) on 2011-11-16**:
Thanks for the update! It's working now.